# Combine mocks and ordinary tests within one test class in Scala

Tags: scala, mocking, tdd

**Code**

*Test*

```
package com.utrecht.numbersequences

import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import org.mockito.Mockito._

class NumberSequencesTests extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter with MockitoSugar {
  test("randomInteger") {
    val m = mock[NumberSequences]
    when(m.randomInteger(5)).thenReturn(5)
    assert(5 === m.randomInteger(5))
  }

  test("squareRoot") {
    assert(NumberSequences.squareRoot(25) === 5)
  }
}
```

*Main*

```
package com.utrecht.numbersequences

import scala.collection.immutable.Stream.consWrapper

class NumberSequences {
  def randomInteger(a: Int) : Int = {
    scala.util.Random.nextInt(a) + 1
  }

  def squareRoot(a: Double) : Double = {
    math.sqrt(a)
  }
}
```

**Outcome**

*Expected*

```
> test
[info] NumberSequencesTests:
[info] - randomInteger
[info] - squareRoot
[info] Passed: Total 2, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 2
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Aug 10, 2014 11:46:44 AM
>
```

*Current*

In order to test *squareRoot* the NumberSequences class needs to be changed into an object. Once this has been done, the squareRoot can be tested, but the mock fails. Once this has been reversed, the mock test passes, but the squareRoot test fails again.

```
> test
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\path\to\developme
nt\scalaNumberSequences\target\scala-2.10\test-classes...
[error] C:\path\to\scalaNumberSequences\src
\test\scala\com\utrecht\numbersequences\NumberSequencesTest.scala:16: not found:
 value NumberSequences
[error]     assert(NumberSequences.squareRoot(25) === 5)
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Aug 10, 2014 11:47:13 AM
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to instantiate a `NumberSequences` object, since it's a `class`, not an `object` or `companion object`.

```
assert(new NumberSequences().squareRoot(25) === 5)
```

To use this syntax:

```
assert(NumberSequences.squareRoot(25) === 5)
```

you would need this:

```
object NumberSequences {
    def squareRoot(a: Double) : Double = {
      math.sqrt(a)
    }
}
```

But since you need to mock it (in the first test), I would rather use the first solution: instantiating the class.